# Django always failed when login as user, while superuser (admin) always success

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

So, I've tried a couple of times to register and back to login. Always failed to log in *except for* **superuser or admin**. Already checked in Django admin that the user that I have registered already there.

There is no error message in the terminal when login or register a user. Except for the error message that I've created in views.py if log in unsuccessful.

So, let's take a look into my code. First views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout

def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":

        # Attempt to sign user in
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        # Check if authenticate successful
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
        else:
            context = {
                "message": "Invalid username and/or password"
            }
            return render(request, "page/login.html", context)
    else:
        return render(request, "page/login.html")

def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        email = request.POST["email"]

        # Ensure password matches with password confirmation
        password = request.POST["password"]
        confirmation = request.POST["confirmation"]
        if password != confirmation:
            context = {
                "message": "Both password must match"
            }
            return render(request, "page/register.html", context)
        
        # Attempt to create new user
        try:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username)
            user.save()
        except IntegrityError:
            context = {
                "message": "Username already exist"
            }
            return render(request, "page/register.html", context)
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
    else:
        return render(request, "page/register.html")
```

And below is the template both for log in and register.

```
<!-- Logintemplate -->
<div class="login-register">
            <div class="head">
                Log in to Explore
            </div>
            <form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username"">
                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="d-grid gap-2">
                    <input class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit" value="Login">
                </div>
                <div id="log-reg">
                    <a href="{% url 'register' %}">Sign Up</a>
                </div>
            </form>
            {% if message %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger mt-4" role="alert">
                {{ message }}
            </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>

<!-- Register template -->
<div class="login-register">
            <div class="head">
                Create your account
            </div>
            <form action="{% url 'register' %}" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" autofocus type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username">
                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="name@example.com">
                    <label for="email">Email address</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmation" name="confirmation" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                    <label for="confirmation">Password Confirmation</label>
                </div>
                <div class="d-grid gap-2">
                    <input class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit" value="Register">
                </div>
                <div id="log-reg">
                    Already have an account? <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In here.</a>
                </div>
            </form> 
            {% if message %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger mt-4" role="alert">
                {{ message }}
            </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
```

Is there something I missed or action that I need to perform?

Comment: Show how you register the users.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat you mean my views.py for register function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create the user as follows:

```
user = User.objects.create_user(username)
```

This creates a user **without** a password which means your user would not be able to login. pass the username and password **both** to the `create_user` method:

```
user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
```

> **Note**: Use a **form class** to make forms in Django to perform validation and cleaning. For making a user use the
> [`UserCreationForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm)

Comment: Thankyou, I missed that. But, in admin each user already have hashed password, why? Is that password auto generate by django?

Comment: @IdoYudhatama when you don't provide a password Django just stores a value which you can never get by hashing some plain text. (Basically an unusable password because nothing can hash to that) Check these lines in the [source code - GitHub](https://github.com/django/django/blob/f83214a3e15ccadc9e2370dd157ed19bcdb07e2c/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py#L74-L75) if you want to know more.